# how we make dynamic x-path in which middle part is of x path is static and rest are dynamic

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For example : i have an xpath -

`//*[@id=':5v.0B601mzFemQrgNFh3c183UFZ3RFU']`

In which every time only `0B601mzFemQrg` part is static rest are dynamic so,how we handle this condition.

Please provide me a solution

Comment: //*[contains(text(), '0B601mzFemQrg')] use this, text only matches the part of text

Comment: U try my xpath, if it is use please upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains` to find partial id

```
//*[contains(@id, '0B601mzFemQrg')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
//*[contains(text(), '0B601mzFemQrg')]
```